Anime where a popular girl dates a guy named Hiryomana or something like that
Saw this is a YouTube short, wanted to know what it was. The scene it showed was like a girl walking through the hallways and guys were saying stuff like "What's a grade A chick doing with a guy like Hiryomana?" and they said something about class 1. I'm very interested, so anything helps!

https://horimiya.fandom.com/wiki/Horimiya_(Anime)?

Yes! Thank you!

This is Horimiya. The name 'Horimiya' is actually a portmanteau of two character's names; Kyouko Hori and Izumi Miyamura, but everything else fits.
She's a popular gyaru, but secretly has to look after her little brother, and he's bookish, but secretly cool. People can't work out why they're dating.

Admired at school for her friendly attitude and academic achievements, high school student Kyouko Hori has been hiding another side of herself. With her parents often away from home due to work, Hori also has to look after her younger brother and do the housework, leaving no opportunities to make friends and socialize outside of school. Meanwhile, Izumi Miyamura is seen as a brooding, glasses-wearing, otaku. In reality, he is a gentle person hopeless at studying. He also has nine piercings hidden behind his long hair and a tattoo along his back and left shoulder.
By sheer happenstance, Hori and Miyamura cross paths outside of school—neither looking as the other expects. These seemingly polar opposites become fast friends, sharing with each other a side of themselves they have never shown to anyone else.




